# Modified struct in some functions changes pointer and causes free() to fail

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, memory-address

Pardon me for running multiple statements on one line, but this is what I don't understand. I have three functions named function1, function2 and function3 and each call makeblock, makeblock2, and makeblock3 respectively. See code below. I was trying to get them all to produce the same result on the screen. makeblock function works properly and the result after calling function1 is:

```
1 A
2 B
```

function2 and function3 do not work properly and produce a segmentation fault when attempting to free the memory pointer. I suspect it has to do with how the pointer is handled in makeblock2 and makeblock3 functions respectively.

So basically, I'm looking for a shortcut to making the data accessible without returning a modified address value back to the caller. Something shorter than `block* dat=*datain;block** data=&dat;` would be ideal provided it works yet my attempts in makeblock2 and makeblock3 have failed.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{int a;char b;} block;

void printdata(block* data){
    while(data->a != 0){printf("%d %c\n",data->a,data->b);data++;}
}

void makeblock3(block** datain){
    block** data=&(*datain);
    (**data).a=1;(**data).b='A';(*data)++;
    (**data).a=2;(**data).b='B';(*data)++;
}

void makeblock2(block** datain){
    block** data=datain;
    (**data).a=1;(**data).b='A';(*data)++;
    (**data).a=2;(**data).b='B';(*data)++;
}

void makeblock(block** datain){
    block* dat=*datain;block** data=&dat;
    (**data).a=1;(**data).b='A';(*data)++;
    (**data).a=2;(**data).b='B';(*data)++;
}

void function1(){block* data=calloc(1,100000);makeblock(&data);printdata(data);free(data);}
void function3(){block* data=calloc(1,100000);makeblock3(&data);printdata(data);free(data);}
void function2(){block* data=calloc(1,100000);makeblock2(&data);printdata(data);free(data);}

int main(){function3();return 0;}
```

Comment: As I asked in some other question of yours, why do you want to pass the argument by reference?

Comment: The two questions are not related. I'm asking this one because I want to learn something new. I'm passing by reference because I want to modify any value I want in a struct within a function yet still be able to use the same pointer from outside of the function which is what happens when function1 is called, but I'm trying to do a shorter cleaner version.

Comment: You don't need to pass the _pointer to the struct_ by reference. You can modify the struct from the pointer. My first function will work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution: don't pass by reference

```
void makeblock(block* data){
    data->a=1; data->b='A'; data++;
    data->a=2; data->b='B'; data++;
}
```

If you really want to pass by reference but don't want the referred object to change (which is contrary to the usual reason to pass by reference), then make a copy of the referred-to object:

```
void makeblock(block** data_p){
    block* data = *data_p;
    data->a=1; data->b='A'; data++;
    data->a=2; data->b='B'; data++;
}
```

Comment: I thought external structs had to be always passed by reference for a function to modify them. It seems to be that way for external numerical variable types. Maybe the manuals are overcomplicating things.

Comment: @Mike: If you have a pointer to an object, you can modify that object through the pointer. So if you want to modify an `int`, you need to pass a pointer to the `int`. Now, you can pass a struct directly to a function (in which case the function gets a copy), but that's usually discouraged because of the cost of making the copy. So you often pass a pointer to the struct. But you are not actually trying to pass a struct. You are trying to pass by reference an array of structs. Because arrays decay to pointers, the effect is the same as passing a pointer to the first element.